# Is this the optimum query for what I'm trying to do in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I'm running a number of queries that merge constantly-changing data into a master table and one of the queries (below) seems to be running quite slowly.

The set up is as follows: `products` table and `products_temp` table have identical structures. New data goes into the `products_temp` table, then I run queries similar to the one below to merge the new data with the master `products` table.

```
INSERT INTO products ( name, brand, price, feeds_id, img_url, referral_url, productid, isbn, ean, upc )
SELECT name, brand, price, feeds_id, img_url, referral_url, productid, isbn, ean, upc
FROM products_temp 
WHERE feeds_id = 449
AND productid NOT IN (
    SELECT productid
    FROM products
    WHERE feeds_id = 449
)
```

Both of these tables have indexes on the `feeds_id` but I have a feeling that isn't making any difference.

As an example `products` may contain over 3.5 million rows and `products_temp` may contain 50,000 to merge `products`.

So my question really is how long should that take? How quick can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

It is, this technique is called [Shadow Table trick](http://www.ovaistariq.net/category/mysql-2/).

Answer (score 0):

You may drop index on `feeds_id` and add a unique key on (`feeds_id`, `productid`) in the main table. Thus, you will be able to use `INSERT IGNORE` for merging. Pay attention to the order of fields in index - `feeds_id` must be first, so you can perform a search by `feeds_id` using this index.

`NOT IN` may cause a slowdown. Depending on what's inside the parenthesis, the query may get stuck in the 'preparing' state.

If you still experience slowdowns, use `EXPLAIN` or the profiling feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring the query and set it up as a LEFT JOIN checking for NULL on the right side

```
INSERT INTO products ( name, brand, price, feeds_id,
img_url, referral_url, productid, isbn, ean, upc )
SELECT A.name, A.brand, A.price,
A.feeds_id, A.img_url, A.referral_url,
A.productid, A.isbn, A.ean, A.upc
FROM
(SELECT * FROM products_temp A WHERE feeds_id = 449) A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT productid FROM products WHERE feeds_id = 449) B
USING (productid)
WHERE B.productid IS NULL;
```

also make sure you have this index

```
ALTER TABLE products_temp ADD INDEX feeds_id (feeds_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

you should greatly avoid WHERE x not in (select xxx). The mysql query optimizer is very bugged with subqueries and will ignore indexes for example.